# Openlayers style the CSS feature popup

Tags: css, openlayers

Might anyone know of a way to style the CSS of a popup used in Openlayers?

Using an OL popup method, returned is a div with an ID of

Would I just add that to my CSS and style, or might there be a better way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Properties:

There are [properties](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Popup-js.html) such as `backgroundColor`, `border`, `opacity` you can set directly.

Have you taken a look at the [`popupMatrix` example](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.11/examples/popupMatrix.html)?

## JQuery:

In case you use jquery, you can reference the DOM Elements by doing:

```
popup.contentDiv
popup.groupDiv
popup.closeDiv
```

[Reference](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Popup-js.html)

## CSS:

Yes, and nothing is stopping you from using css like I demonstrate in this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/BLLqB/1/

## Conclusion:

The better way is the one which works best for what you're doing. If you see that the available styling properties are not enough, use jQuery or CSS.